# Using diskpart for unallocated space during windows 10 installation

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, diskpart

I'm a newbee and excuse my bad english. Here is my stituation.
The hard drive was 2 partitions and i deleted primary (system) one. Now its seem as unallocated space. I read the following answer of the question and i tried to create a new partition.
 But i'm confused, there is one disk seen on "list disk" and i got some important data on partition 2.I dont want to format whole disk.If i type "create partition primary size=93" it looks like suceeed but i want to be sure is it safe way?
I just want to allocate that space and make installation there.

The topic i reffered:

[How create new partition on an unallocated space using diskpart?](https://superuser.com/questions/825017/how-create-new-partition-on-an-unallocated-space-using-diskpart)
[snapshot of my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiJbE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Prompt and type "Diskpart"

Next, type "List Volume"

Identify which volume contains your important data, you need to delete all the other volumes apart from this.

Then, type "Select Volume [number of volume to delete]

Finally, "delete volume"

Repeat this until you can only see your important data volume and unallocated space.

Then "create partition primary" will create a primary partition that fills the remaining space before the important data volume. Note you do not need to indicate size.

I would consider using a linux live CD and GParted, a program that allows you to see the partition layout on the disk, and move and create new partitions while being able to easily visualise what you are doing, see the below screenshot:

[image: GParted]

If you want to use this instead GParted is [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) and links to the instructions are on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition), its quite easy to pick up.

Use `help` or visit [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465(v=ws.10).aspx) to see a list of all available commands for diskpart if needed.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. The link that you given is not found.

Comment: I tried "list volume" command and cmd respond me to change drive type do "dynamic". I did it but everything messed up for me. Can you explain the process step by step please? Here is the screenshots https://1drv.ms/i/s!AuqKZViU2CO9jXABqL1itbzDNiaZ  ,  https://1drv.ms/i/s!AuqKZViU2CO9jXZJH6sKEDscE-S6

Comment: Sorry about the link! I have edited it to work now. I'll edit my answer to outline the steps you'll need

Comment: Answer edited with specific steps.

Comment: Unallocated dynamic volume was not seen on the list anymore. I installed lubuntu and tried resize the disk with gparted but it has consistently failed (an error). The solution was very traditonal:). I used an external hard drive enclosure and connected a different PC. Data backed up and converted to basic disk again:) Thanks for your kindly support.I appreciate it.

Comment: Ah well I am very pleased to hear you found a solution, you're very welcome!